# Why do I get a lowercase character using marshaller in Java?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to marshall specific data to format XML document. I'm using this function :

```
public String marshall(EntiteDynamiqueWrapper wrap) throws DocthequeException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    LOG.debug(wrap.toString());

    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(wrap.getCurrentClass());
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);  

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(wrap.getClassInstance(), sw);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        LOG.error("Error marshalling the entity : " + wrap.getId(), e);
        throw new DocthequeException(
                "Error marshalling the entity : " + wrap.getId(), e);
    }
    LOG.debug(sw.toString());
    return sw.toString();
}
```

On first LOG.debug i got :

```
wrapper name : L_COM_ET_CVCM_REFUS_OUV_CPT_PRO
champs du wrapper :
AMT_CVCM_AFF_CODE_BARRE
AMT_DO_CODE_POSTAL_CLIENT
AMT_DO_INTITULE1_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DO_INTITULE2_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DO_LIGNE3_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DO_LIGNE4_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DO_LIGNE5_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DO_LIGNE6_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DO_NO_COMPTE
AMT_DO_VILLE_ADRESSE_CLIENT
AMT_DT_CVCM_CODE_BARRE
AMT_DT_CVCM_DEMATER
AMT_DT_CVCM_TYPEIMP
AMT_DT_ENVIRONNEMENT_CICS
AMT_DT_IDWO
A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO
L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO
```

Result from marshaller :

> ```
>  <L_COM_ET_CVCM_REFUS_OUV_CPT_PRO>
>       <AMT_CVCM_AFF_CODE_BARRE/>
>       <AMT_DO_CODE_POSTAL_CLIENT></AMT_DO_CODE_POSTAL_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_INTITULE1_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_INTITULE1_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_INTITULE2_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_INTITULE2_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE3_ADRESSE_CLIENT/>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE4_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_LIGNE4_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE5_ADRESSE_CLIENT/>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE6_ADRESSE_CLIENT/>
>       <AMT_DO_NO_COMPTE></AMT_DO_NO_COMPTE>
>       <AMT_DO_VILLE_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_VILLE_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DT_CVCM_CODE_BARRE/>
>       <AMT_DT_CVCM_DEMATER></AMT_DT_CVCM_DEMATER>
>       <AMT_DT_CVCM_TYPEIMP></AMT_DT_CVCM_TYPEIMP>
>       <AMT_DT_ENVIRONNEMENT_CICS/>
>       <AMT_DT_IDWO/>
>       <a_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO/>
>       <l_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO/>
>   </L_COM_ET_CVCM_REFUS_OUV_CPT_PRO>
> ```

expected :

> ```
>  <L_COM_ET_CVCM_REFUS_OUV_CPT_PRO>
>       <AMT_CVCM_AFF_CODE_BARRE/>
>       <AMT_DO_CODE_POSTAL_CLIENT></AMT_DO_CODE_POSTAL_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_INTITULE1_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_INTITULE1_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_INTITULE2_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_INTITULE2_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE3_ADRESSE_CLIENT/>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE4_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_LIGNE4_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE5_ADRESSE_CLIENT/>
>       <AMT_DO_LIGNE6_ADRESSE_CLIENT/>
>       <AMT_DO_NO_COMPTE></AMT_DO_NO_COMPTE>
>       <AMT_DO_VILLE_ADRESSE_CLIENT></AMT_DO_VILLE_ADRESSE_CLIENT>
>       <AMT_DT_CVCM_CODE_BARRE/>
>       <AMT_DT_CVCM_DEMATER></AMT_DT_CVCM_DEMATER>
>       <AMT_DT_CVCM_TYPEIMP></AMT_DT_CVCM_TYPEIMP>
>       <AMT_DT_ENVIRONNEMENT_CICS/>
>       <AMT_DT_IDWO/>
>       <A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO/>
>       <L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO/>
>   </L_COM_ET_CVCM_REFUS_OUV_CPT_PRO>
> ```

Why marshal put me a lowercase on fields A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO and L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO ?

I noticed that it only appends if i got only 1 character before underscore. No problem is the field is named AT_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: What is the value of the field before the marshall. I think you might be switching between uppercase and lowercase depending on the field value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB Java generating XML, Why lowercase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879433/jaxb-java-generating-xml-why-lowercase)

Comment: @MatíasW.  Values before marshal are :
    'AMT_DT_IDWO
    A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO
    L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO'

Comment: @Marcx About the other  topic, i'll check, but my fields are dynamic, but maybe it doesn't change anything

Comment: I imagine you have a bean with all fields declared, you should check the annotation in this/those class/es

Comment: @Marcx it's not that simple because those fields come from a external file.  Users fill the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following in  your EntiteDynamiqueWrapper  class:

```
@XmlElement( name = "A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO")
private SomeType A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO; // ( or your field       A_COURDEST_CD_TICIV_L028_LO);

@XmlElement( name = "L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO")
 private SomeType L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO;(  // Or your field bind to   L_COM_ADRES_BDF_CO );
```

Comment: As I said before, my fields are dynamic filled by final users. It's not a good solution to me, because it means the user cannot change or add a field.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get my fields uppercased. I just applied a regex with this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<[a-z]_|</[a-z]_").matcher(strToTransform);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int last = 0;
            while (m.find()) {
                sb.append(strToTransform.substring(last, m.start()));
                sb.append(m.group(0).toUpperCase());
                last = m.end();
            }
            sb.append(strToTransform.substring(last));
            return sb.toString();
```